# What happened to System.TypeCode of value 17

Tags: .net, system.type

The enum [System.TypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx) is defined as follows:

```
public enum TypeCode
{
   Empty = 0,
   Object = 1,
   DBNull = 2,
   Boolean = 3,
   Char = 4,
   SByte = 5,
   Byte = 6,
   Int16 = 7,
   UInt16 = 8,
   Int32 = 9,
   UInt32 = 10,
   Int64 = 11,
   UInt64 = 12,
   Single = 13,
   Double = 14,
   Decimal = 15,
   DateTime = 16,
   String = 18,
}
```

Out of curiosity, what happened to TypeCode of value 17? Has it ever existed? Why has TypeCode.String the value of 18 and not 17?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [following blog post](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/adrian/archive/2008/03/17/91755.aspx) explains *the hole*:

> This is a good question. I was digging through the history of this
>   file to see if I could figure out what happened, and it’s not clear.
>   We’ve had this “hole” in the TypeCode enum since October of 2000, and
>   I can’t find an older set of bits. But, I’m sure that comment in
>   IConvertible is right – this used to be TimeSpan. For TimeSpan, it’s
>   possible we thought it would be interesting for a while, then we
>   realized that frankly not that many people need to convert a Decimal
>   to a TimeSpan, then removed it.
>
> You might ask why we didn’t “fix” the enum when we removed whichever
>   of these values we had originally added. It turns out that whenever we
>   have a breaking change internally, we need to recompile all the code
>   that might possibly depend on the removed or changed public surface
>   area. For us, that would mean rebuilding everything that might have
>   referred to TypeCode.String, whose value would have changed from 18 to
>   17. While we do go through that process internally in DevDiv, it is
>   costly & painful for us.